# Which has better signal: RCA jacks or RF(Coaxial)

Tags: video-capture, signal-strength

When capturing old VHS(or cable) to PC, which jacks to use for the highest quality? RCA(composite) or RF? If the PC card supports it would S-video/component be better? Is there a general signal strength comparison between these different connectors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you're dealing with analog signals, it depends on many factors:

- source quality (e.g. VHS recording)
- sending device - internal quality and connector quality
- cable shielding & quality
- external RF interference
- receiving device - internal quality and connector quality

Generally, S-video would be your best bet, seconded by RCA (composite). Be aware though: I have seen systems where the S-video is actually poorer than composite due to the receiving or sending device being bad, so try both if possible. RF will be the weakest and is most susceptible to interference.

Few tips:

- Find cables that have ferrite cores (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrite_core), which help reduce noise
- Make sure your cables are as short as possible and well away from power cords or potential sources of interference.
- Try not to run household appliances when recording / transferring. Examples: Blenders, microwaves, vacuums, power tools, etc.

Comment: Basic TV Signal Quality ladder:

RF/Coax ==> Composite/RCA ==> S-Video (separate Luminance & Chrominance) ==> Components (Separate Color Channels)

Answer (score 1):

In the analog days of yore, component was always the preferred method of connecting video equipment simply because the video and the two audio signals all had their own separate carrier and thus would not interfere with each other.

S-Video was even better because of the same principle, separating out the video components onto their own carriers as well.

Be aware, however, that we're talking analog signaling here.  Cable quality is a very significant concern as is the length of the cables and the amount of ambient interference in the environment.  Also the equipment quality plays a big factor.

For the best possible quality, use very short, high quality S-video cables, and do the capture in a room that's as far away from your WiFi, microwaves, cell phones, etc. as possible.

Answer (score 0):

RF signal is made by taking Composite signal and then modulating it over a ~60MHz carrier[1](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RF_modulator)  [2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Television_channel_frequencies)

So RCA/Composite is more pure (better) than RF. You also get rid of having to tune it.

From my short experience it's very rare that you get worse signal in RCA, only in cases of bad grounding.